# Exclude header and footer from popup overlay

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like my header and footer to be accessible when a page has an overlay due to a popup menu (as seen on http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html).
So in a nutshell, only the div with attribute 'data-role=content"' should have the overlay applied.
If possible, this should be achieved using a minimum of extra CSS and/or JavaScript. I've looked through the entire jQuery Mobile docs, but haven't found any reference to my problem.

Some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Context Menu</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquerymobile.com/test/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button">Menu</a>

                <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-overlay-theme="b">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="width: 200px">
                        <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Manage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

So in this exmaple, the header and footer shouldn't be overlayed when the Menu link is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `z-index` css property allows you to set the way the different "layers" of your page are superposed. A fixed header in jquery mobile has a `z-index` of 1000.
By setting the `z-index` of your overlay to a value below 1000, it will be displayed "under" the header.